# $.ajax not working while working with fullcalendar js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using the [Smart Admin Theme](https://bootstraphunter.com/theme/smartadmin-responsive-webapp-frontend-BSH01) and currently I am trying to work with the [calendar](http://192.241.236.31/themes/preview/smartadmin/1.5/ajaxversion/#ajax/calendar.html) page.

The basic functionality of the calendar is already defined and ready to use. New events can be created and dropped on the map.

I am working on the persistence of these events and I am currently working to store the events that are dropped on the map in the DB. There is drop method defined which is rendering the event on the calendar and I have modified it slightly to send an ajax request to the server to store the event too.

Here is the original version:

```
drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

    // assign it the date that was reported
    copiedEventObject.start = date;
    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

    // render the event on the calendar
    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

    // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
        $(this).remove();
    }

},
```

And here is my version of the method with the ajax call:

```
drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

    // assign it the date that was reported
    copiedEventObject.start = date;
    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

    // render the event on the calendar
    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/events',
        data: copiedEventObject,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });

    // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
        $(this).remove();
    }

},
```

I am getting an error saying:

> TypeError: a is undefined

This error is generated my moment.js library.

I tried commenting out a few lines in my ajax call and it seems that the line which says:

```
data: copiedEventObject,
```

is the one responsible, because when I commented it out, the ajax call was successful, but I cannot understand why.

Tried this out too:

```
data: {
    title: copiedEventObject.title,
    description: copiedEventObject.description,
    class: copiedEventObject.className,
    start: copiedEventObject.start,
    end: copiedEventObject.end,
    icon: copiedEventObject.icon
},
```

Got the same error. Commented it `start`. Works fine again.

Chrome has a more verbose error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'month' of undefined

Comment: What is logged when you put a `console.log(copiedEventObject)` in your code?

Comment: So how looks like `copiedEventObject`?

Comment: @devqon : It is being logged perfectly. In fact I have used the same code for an older version of full calendar which was not dependant on moment.js and it worked fine back then.

Comment: @Rohan what is the value of the start property?

Comment: It is an object. A moment object itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I had to take data out of the copiedEventObject and manually create a data object to make the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the data attribute to corect json:

```
data: JSON.stringify(copiedEventObject);
```

Comment: copiedEventObject is not a json object and cannot be converted in json

Comment: i sugest you take what you want to pass to ajax from this object and create a new json valid object

Comment: I did now. Everything works fine except the start object. I commented it out and it works fine again. What do I do now? Chrome gives a more verbose error for the same thing: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'month' of undefined`

Comment: copiedEventObject.month does not exist or is empty use a if to check if exist